# Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter when using ListView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have an activity Mainactivity, in this when a button is pressed then it will show a listview. But in

listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);

I am getting "Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter (anonymous android view.View.OnClickListener, int, int, java.lang.String)"

My outer class is "Mainactivity" I tried "Mainactivity.this" instead of "this". But It is showing "cannot resolve constructor" error.

MainActivity class extends Actionbaractivity implements onItemelectedListner

My code is:

ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(cnt.getText().toString().length() > 0 &&
                    number.getText().toString().length() > 0 &&
                    Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString()) > 0 &&
                    Integer.parseInt(cnt.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                    number.requestFocus();
                    String[] value = new String{"hello","world"};

                    try {
                        temp_count = temp_count + Integer.parseInt(cnt.getText().toString());
                        count.setText(String.valueOf(temp_count));
                        temp_amt = temp_amt + (Integer.parseInt(cnt.getText().toString()) * tkt_rate);
                        amount.setText(String.valueOf(temp_amt));

                        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);

                        lstView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                        lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {

                                SparseBooleanArray checked = lstView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                                int size = checked.size(); // number of name-value pairs in the array
                                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                                    int key = checked.keyAt(i);
                                    boolean value = checked.get(key);
                                    if (value) {
                                        row = lstView.getChildAt(i);
                                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5"));
                                    } else {
                                        row = lstView.getChildAt(i);
                                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Please help...

Comment: You need to pass array or arraylist. Post your log.

Comment: i need to pass array, question updated. i am getting compile time errors

Comment: copy the full sentence of the error and paste here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error shows that you are putting `android view.View.OnClickListener` as the first argument.

I know you said you have tried, but you really need to use `Mainactivity.this`. If it is not working please post the code of the start of your java file.

Also is your activity named as `Mainactivity`? Remember it is case sensitive, should it be `MainActivity`? If so, you have to use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
 Button add;
    Button ok;
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_new);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: //above comment continues
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>((Activity)this,
                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);

                            lstView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                            lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                        int position, long id) {

Comment: then obviously you should use `new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);`

Comment: I tried:
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);
but getting "cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(app.mysqlapp.MainActivity,int,int,java.lang.String)'" error

Comment: your line `String[] value = new String{"hello","world"};` is looking strange, are you sure you post it right? it should not compile

Comment: make sure it should be `String[] value = new String[]{"hello","world"};`

Comment: Many thanks... :-)
I was using String[] value = new String{"hello","world"};
It worked with String[] value = new String[]{"hello","world"};....

Comment: Glad that it helped. Please kindly accept and upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening because your class implements onclicklistener. So can you try cast `this` to `Activity`? Like the code below:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter((Activity)this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);
```

Comment: i tried this. still getting error as "inConvertible Types, cannot cast Anonymos android.view.View.onClickListner to Android.app.Activity"..

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter needs `Context` as the first argument. What you can do is to have a field reference to your `Context`, like the followings.

1. Added a field to your Activity, `private Context mContext;`
2. Inside the onCreate() of your Activity, `mContext = this;`
3. Use the mContext to construct ArrayAdapter, `listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, value);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                               android.R.id.text1,
                               Collections.singletonList(value));
```